# How to get string case name of a enum whose rawType is Int

Tags: swift, enums

I want a enumeration of countries, like:

```
enum Country: Int {
    case Afghanistan
    case Albania
    case Algeria
    case Andorra
    //...
}
```

There are two main reasons why I choose `Int` as its rawValue type:

1. I want to determine the total count of this enumeration, using `Int` as rawValue type simplifies this:

   ```
   enum Country: Int {
       case Afghanistan
       // other cases
       static let count: Int = {
           var max: Int = 0
           while let _ = Country(rawValue: max) { max = max + 1 }
           return max
       }()
   }
   ```
2. I also need a complicated data structure that represents a country, and there is an array of that data structure. I can easily subscript-access certain country from this array using Int-valued enumeration.

   ```
   struct CountryData {
        var population: Int
        var GDP: Float
   }

   var countries: [CountryData]

   print(countries[Country.Afghanistan.rawValue].population)
   ```

Now, I somehow need to convert a certain `Country` case to `String`(aka. something like

```
let a = Country.Afghanistan.description // is "Afghanistan"
```

Since there are lots of cases, manually writing a conversion-table-like function seems unacceptable.

So, how can I get these features at once ?:

1. Use enumeration so potential typo-caused bugs can be found during compile time. (Country.Afganistan won't compile, there should be an 'h' after 'g', but some approach like countries["Afganistan"] will compile and may cause runtime errors)
2. Be able to determine the total country count programmatically (likely to be able to determine at the compile time, but I don't want to use a literal value and keep in mind to change it properly every time I add or remove a country)
3. Be able to easily subscript-like access a metadata array.
4. Be able to get a string of a `case`.

Using `enum Country: Int` satisfies 1, 2, 3 but not 4

Using `enum Country: String` satisfies 1, 3, 4 but not 2 (use Dictionary instead of Array)

Comment: what's the mean of 'h' after 'g'?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, the "rawType is Int" in this question is unique and essential the question. Answers there say to re-declare the enum as a String type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To print an `enum's` case as `String`, use:

```
String(describing: Country.Afghanistan)
```

You can create you data structure something like:

```
enum Country
{
    case Afghanistan
    case Albania
    case Algeria
    case Andorra
}

struct CountryData
{
    var name : Country
    var population: Int
    var GDP: Float
}

var countries = [CountryData]()
countries.append(CountryData(name: .Afghanistan, population: 2000, GDP: 23.1))
print(countries[0].name)
```

Comment: This answer appears to now be outdated in Swift 5.